# Swing: the initial String of JTextField is an empty String

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, isnullorempty

About the constructor of `JTextField`, the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField()) says:

> **`public JTextField()`**
>
> Constructs a new `TextField`. A default model is created, the initial
>   string is null, and the number of columns is set to 0.

But when I use this constructor, the method `getText()` of `JTextField` returns an empty `String`, for example:

```
boolean b = new JTextField().getText().isEmpty();  // returns true.
```

Why the value returned by `getText()` is an empty `String` instead of `null`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JTextField get the text from the Document , default implementation PlainDocument never returns null. even though you tried to call JTextField.setText(null), it will just clear the value of the Document content, but still getText will return empty string.